# Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'Comparator<T>' to 'Comparator<? super Object>'

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, lower-bound

I found this code in some library:

```
    public static <T> List<T> sort(
        Collection<T> collection,
        Comparator<T> comparator)
    {
        Object[] a = collection.toArray(new Object[collection.size()]);
        //noinspection unchecked
        Arrays.sort(a, (Comparator<? super Object>) comparator);
        return cast(Arrays.asList(a));
    }
```

My checker swears

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast `java.util.Comparator<T>` to
>   '`java.util.Comparator<? super java.lang.Object>`

Under which circumstances this code could work?

Comment: This is bad code. They should have worked with lists and used `Collections.sort` instead of using arrays and relying on erasure like this.

Comment: This compiles in javac and eclipse with a warning. What "checker" are you using?

Comment: My bad; I now realise this is someone else's horrible library code. It will work under all circumstances as you guarantee the compatibility of the `Comparator` and the `Collection`. It's just a rather nasty implementation -  it might predate generics and has been ported?

Comment: Looks like [this](https://github.com/olap4j/olap4j-xmlaserver/blob/master/src/main/java/org/olap4j/xmla/server/impl/Util.java#L360) is the source.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, the code can not work.

I suggest making the following modification:

```
public static <T> List<T> sort(Collection<T> collection, Comparator<T> comparator) {
    List<T> a = new ArrayList<T>(collection);
    a.sort(comparator);
    return a;
}
```

That will fix the compile errors *and* the awfulness in one fell swoop.

<sub>Disclaimer: Code may not compile or work as it was thumbed in on my phone (but there's a reasonable chance it will work)</sub>

Comment: @boris old habits die hard :/

Comment: The code is not OP's and he's not trying to fix it.

Comment: This is quite different from the OP's code. The OP's code returns a sorted copy. This code sorts the list in place (if the collection is a list).

Comment: @shmosel it can't be fixed. Cremation is the only option

Comment: @JBNizet is correct, this code should just call `new ArrayList<T>(collection)` without the test.

Comment: Or `new ArrayList<>(collection)` to be pedantic.

Comment: This is bordering on being a useless method now.

Comment: @vince I thought I answered that - "none" is the answer

Comment: @Bohemian I actually started writing the comment before you edited, forgot to refresh before submitting (was at work, got called in), I'm sorry. But "*that will fix it*" doesn't explain *why* it fixes it, and that's what I was mostly worried about. If he encounters this problem again in a different context, he may not have the proper understanding to fix it, resulting in him coming back and asking the same question (just dressed up a bit differently).